# While loops in Procedures

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, procedure

I am trying to output 1 to 30 days but it isn't working and it says Your code didn't display any output

here is my code:

```
def nextDay(year, month, day):  
        day = 0   
        while (day < 30):  
           day = day + 1
           print day
```

this what they are having me do.  But i am stuck on the day portion.  Sorry i noticed I put month instead of day so i fixed it, but this is what I am trying to get to at the end.

Define a simple nextDay procedure, that assumes every month has 30 days.

For example:

```
nextDay(1999, 12, 30) => (2000, 1, 1)  
nextDay(2013, 1, 30) => (2013, 2, 1)  
nextDay(2012, 12, 30) => (2013, 1, 1)    (even though December really has 31 days)


def nextDay(year, month, day):
"""   
Returns the year, month, day of the next day.  
Simple version: assume every month has 30 days.  
"""
# YOUR CODE HERE  
return
```

Comment: Put `print month` after the line `month = month + 1`

Comment: i put print month and it still gives me the same answer

Comment: All you want to do is to output the 1 to 30?

Comment: Can you please update the code where you have printed the month?

Comment: well the short term goal is to output 1 to 30 but there are other things that need to be done.  just taking it a step at a time but i cant get to the other step without getting this one done first.  i thought while loop would be the best but i am open to suggestions

Comment: If you just want to output numbers from 1 to 30 with this `while` loop, then at this point you don't need a function with year, month and day. If that's what you need then I can show you a simple answer without the function.

Comment: can you show the whole program?

Comment: i haven't tried anything new.  I am completely stuck.  if i do it without the procedure it prints, but i believe i need to do it with the procedure because the procedure was given to me

Comment: Do it manually on a piece of paper.  Take a date and add one day to it to produce the _next_ date.  Do this many times till you notice the pattern of the process of adding a day.  Then describe that pattern in words.  Then try to turn the words into code.

Comment: "if i do it without the procedure it prints..."  Sounds like you're not actually _calling_ the function.  But who knows?  As many people have pointed out to you, _we can't see your program_, just a little bit of it.

Comment: Why are you trying to print 1 through 30 in the first place?  That has _nothing_ to do with your assignment... at least, not the parts you posted.  For that matter, the assignment doesn't say to _print_ anything at all... although it also doesn't seem to return anything, so I suspect you're not telling us everything.  I suggest you read "[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" and especially the external links at the bottom.  We really can't help you like this, except maybe through luck.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you're trying to output 1 through 30 this will work...

```
for x in range(1, 31):
    print 'Day: %d' % x
```

I literally don't get your function at all, as it makes no sense.

In addition, I don't really get why you would use a while loop for that as it is slower than both range and xrange.

Comment: and that is why i am trying to get HELP.  I am new to coding and don't understand what is going on and is why i am on here asking for help.  Please constructive criticism with little condescending remarks.  Thanks

Comment: How do you expect anyone to help you when you don't even provide us with your code?  @kevinwang1219

Comment: This is really hopeless.

Answer (score 0):

Did you want this

```
 def nextDay(year, month, day):
     if day == 30:
         if month == 12:
             day, month = 1, 1
             year+=1
         else:
             month+=1
     else:
         day+=1
     return (year, month, day)

>>>nextDay(2012, 12, 30)
(2013, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you needed.

```
def nextDay(year, month, day):
    day += 1
    if day > 30:
        day = 1
        month += 1
        if month > 12:
            month = 1
            year += 1
    return (year, month, day)
```

Your code did not show anything as I don't think you have called the function.